# 16 bits grayscale PNG and iOS 10.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, png, grayscale

I just updated some of my test devices to iOS 10.2.1. And, for some reason, 16 bits grayscale png images are not displayed correctly, everything is black. So I did create a sample project to reproduce the problem. I am using this code to display the image:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIImageView* image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Test16-3Small.png"]];
image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
image.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:image];
}
```

- Image is black on iPhone 5c and iPad 4th gen
- Image displayed correctly on iPhone 6s and iPad mini 2th gen and simulator.
- Image could be black, even if it is small, so it does not seem to be related to a memory problem.
- Work perfectly on iOS 9.2.1

It is a bug or a new iOS limitation?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a link to one of the images that fail this way? The very least we can do is check if it's well-formed. (A link to a download please. I may be mistaken, but there is a chance that if you use a regular 'upload your image here' site, it'll be silently converted to whatever its maintainers deem useful. We need the original.)

Comment: Thanks for replying! You can easily make a 16 bits grayscale png image by using photoshop... this is what I did! But now, it seem that this problem is fixed in iOS 10.3 beta. Let's see if it is ok in 10.3 release version...